# Make badge count into a clickable button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, design

[image]

Intuitively, it feels like I should be able to click the boxes here and get taken to [this link](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/2322/enderland?tab=badges&sort=class) where it shows them.

It took me a while clicking here to realize there are no buttons there, because they look like buttons in the UI.

I suggest making them buttons that when clicked at least take you to the above link.

Answer (score 6):

While you're at it, these too please!

[image: badges when looking at another person's profile]

(From looking at another person's profile, such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/193412/enderland)